# How to convert java tableswitch to switch-case

Tags: java, android-2.2-froyo

Couple of months ago I coded an android app that basically captured signatures. Couple of days ago my laptop crashed and I lost the code of the project. However, I had the apk file which I used to decompile the source code. However, the decompiled source code is a bit tough for me to digest. so I started recoding it with the help of the decompiled code. But I hit a brick wall trying to figure out this `tableswitch` which corresponds to a switch statement in my actual code. The `tableswitch` is

```
motionevent.getActionMasked();
            JVM INSTR tableswitch 0 2: default 104
        //                       0 286
        //                       1 344
        //                       2 344;
               goto _L1 _L2 _L3 _L3
_L1:
            boolean flag;
            paint.setStrokeWidth(f6);
            Canvas canvas = bgCanvas;
            Path path1 = bgPath;
            Paint paint1 = paint;
            canvas.drawPath(path1, paint1);
            bgPath.reset();
            Path path2 = bgPath;
            float f7 = lastTouchX;
            float f8 = lastTouchY;
            path2.moveTo(f7, f8);
            int i = (int)(dirtyRect.left - 5F);
            int j = (int)(dirtyRect.top - 5F);
            int k = (int)(dirtyRect.right + 5F);
            int l = (int)(dirtyRect.bottom + 5F);
            signature signature1 = this;
            int i1 = i;
            int j1 = j;
            int k1 = k;
            int l1 = l;
            signature1.invalidate(i1, j1, k1, l1);
            lastTouchX = f;
            lastTouchY = f1;
            lastStroke = f6;
            lastPressure = f4;
            flag = true;
_L4:
            return flag;
_L2:
            CustomPath custompath = path;
            float f9 = f3;
            custompath.moveTo(f, f1, f4, f9);
            bgPath.moveTo(f, f1);
            lastStroke = f6;
            lastTouchX = f;
            lastTouchY = f1;
            lastPressure = f4;
            flag = true;
            if (true) goto _L4; else goto _L3
_L3:
            resetDirtyRect(f, f1);
            int i2 = motionevent.getHistorySize();
            int j2 = 0;
            do
            {
label0:
                {
                    if (j2 < i2)
                    {
                        break label0;
                    }
                    path.lineTo(f, f1, f4, f6);
                    if ((double)Math.abs(lastStroke - f6) >= 0.10000000000000001D)
                    {
                        Paint paint2 = paint;
                        float f10 = lastStroke;
                        paint2.setStrokeWidth(f10);
                        Canvas canvas1 = bgCanvas;
                        Path path3 = bgPath;
                        Paint paint3 = paint;
                        canvas1.drawPath(path3, paint3);
                        bgPath.reset();
                        Path path4 = bgPath;
                        float f11 = lastTouchX;
                        float f12 = lastTouchY;
                        path4.moveTo(f11, f12);
                    }
                    bgPath.lineTo(f, f1);
                }
                if (true)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                float f13 = motionevent.getHistoricalX(j2);
                float f14 = motionevent.getHistoricalY(j2);
                float f15 = (float)Math.round(motionevent.getHistoricalPressure(j2) * 100F) / 100F;
                float f16 = f15 * 10F;
                float f17 = Math.max(1F, f16);
                MotionEvent motionevent2 = motionevent;
                byte byte1 = 25;
                float f18 = motionevent2.getHistoricalAxisValue(byte1, j2);
                path.lineTo(f13, f14, f15, f18);
                if ((double)Math.abs(lastStroke - f17) >= 0.10000000000000001D)
                {
                    Paint paint4 = paint;
                    float f19 = lastStroke;
                    paint4.setStrokeWidth(f19);
                    Canvas canvas2 = bgCanvas;
                    Path path5 = bgPath;
                    Paint paint5 = paint;
                    canvas2.drawPath(path5, paint5);
                    bgPath.reset();
                    Path path6 = bgPath;
                    float f20 = lastTouchX;
                    float f21 = lastTouchY;
                    path6.moveTo(f20, f21);
                }
                bgPath.lineTo(f13, f14);
                lastTouchX = f13;
                lastTouchY = f14;
                lastStroke = f17;
                j2++;
            } while (true);
            if (true) goto _L1; else goto _L5
_L5:
```

in my actual code the switch cases were something like this

```
switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    // codes here
    break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
    // codes here
    break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
    // codes here
    break;
    default:
    break;
}
```

The problem is I can't figure out which Label corresponds to which case. Can anyone shed some light on it?

Comment: This is your code and if you dont understand, then how can you expect us to understand it. However The stumbling point here is `if (true) goto XXX`. This statement will never let you go inside `else` block. Moreover `goto` statement are really hard to debug and understand the flow of program. I will suggest not to rely on this decompiled code. and start this piece from scratch.

Comment: my code had four cases and the tableswitch has four labels `goto _L1 _L2 _L3 _L3`. Now since there are two consecutive `_L3`s, I think they correspond to `case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:`. I am not sure about the other two. That's what I want to know. Since I don't know how tableswitch works, I am asking for other's opinions.

Comment: @th1rdey3 If you see all the way down to posted code. You will see at very last and line before that has `_L5:`. Moreover the problem I have also noted in my previous comment. YOu can make assumption as much as you want and waste your time while understanding this code. Don't do that, just start from scratch.

Comment: the code will never go to `_L5:`, you pointed that out yourself. and if you look into `_L4`, you will see a `return` statement, which is the exit point. My question is about `_L1` and `_L2`. what corresponds to which case. And my question has nothing to do it whether I have to do it from scratch or not. That's not the answer I  am looking for.